# htaccess rewritecond for url with asterisks

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, asterisk

Some... fine person... has set up an incoming link to our site that looks like:
`http://www.site.com/*our*-*services*/`

I'd like to redirect it so it points it to:
`http://www.site.com/our-services/`

Ours is a Wordpress site so there's some rewrite stuff in our root htaccess file already. A rule that simply removes asterisks from the URL would do, but I can't figure out how to do that, so I tried the following - loosely based on copying the existing Wordpress rules - which isn't working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/\*our\*-\*services\*/)
RewriteRule . /our-services/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

It looks like this rule is being ignored - the errant URL currently redirects you to our default Wordpress 404 page. Clearly, I am fail: what should I have put as the rewrite condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd remove your first `RewriteCond` and then just use this rule:

`RewriteRule \*our\*-\*services\*\/ /our-services/ [L]`

Answer (score 1):

Well get them to change there incoming link.

Asterisks are reserved in urls, so in this case it shouldn't be used:

[W3 Url Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html)

[Allowing asterisk in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567215/allowing-asterisk-in-url)