# Web API self host - bind on all network interfaces with a valid Uri

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to bind a self host web api on all network interface.
The common usage si provided in this other question:
[Web API self host - bind on all network interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598042/web-api-self-host-bind-on-all-network-interfaces) .
However the asterisk is not accepted in the base adress.
The following code:

```
string baseAddress = string.Format("http://*:9000/"); 
config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress)
```

will throw a "System.UriFormatException"

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144858/c-sharp-uri-cannot-have-asterisk-in-domain-name-but-java-and-php-can) "*" is forbidden in Uri but then I am wondering if there would be an other way to define such a base address?

Comment: Did you try `http://+:9000/`

Comment: @Gerben I also get a System.UriFormatException. You are right, this one should have worked if the problem was the asterisk. I think I don't understand what happens there.

Comment: What if you drop the last forward slash? `http://+:9000`

Comment: @Gerben same problem. Basically I was working with http://localhost:8080 (everything was okay) and I replaced by a symbol afterward so I can tell for sure that the rest of the line is okay. I just realize that my code sample does not mention any asterisk btw. I have to correct that.